# How to wrap bash commands after adding color

Tags: bash, prompt

My current .bash_profile is equal to the below. I add some color and add a command that outputs whether or not I am in a git repository to my PS1 for my bash profile.

```
ORIG=$PS1
PS1="\[${txtund}${green}\]LOCAL\[\[${reset}\]";
PS1+="\$(prompt_git \"${white} on ${violet}\")";
PS1+="\[${reset}\]";
PS1+=" - \u\$: ";
```

The problem is that when I run long commands, it is rewriting over the line. I want to word wrap my commands so that as I write they go to the next line. What do I need to wrap the PS1 in for this to occur?

UPDATE -

```
ORIG=$PS1
PS1="\[${txtund}${green}\]LOCAL\[\[${reset}\]";
PS1+="\$(prompt_git \"\[${white}\] on \[${violet}\]\")";
PS1+="\[${reset}\]";
PS1+=" - \u\$: ";
```

I have increased the number of escapes as per the comment from below. The wrap is still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I see you have enclosed most of the non-printing characters in `\[ \]` except the colours on the second line. Try enclosing them as well.

Comment: @muru I have updated the file. Still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: @muru I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORIG=$PS1
PS1="\[${txtund}${green}\]LOCAL\[\[${reset}\]";
PS1+="\$(prompt_git \"\[${white}\] on \[${violet}\]\")";
PS1+="\[${reset}\]";
PS1+="\[ - \u\$: \]";
```

I have escaped both the colors as well as the final line of text. This solves my issue. It is through using [ ] and escaping colors as well as text, I am able to word wrap my commands in bash correctly.